# Applying different CSS to top 10 results of a query

Tags: php, mysql, css

The table below prints of the results of a query called $sqlStr3.  It works fine.  The query is set to return the top 25 results.

I would like to apply a unique CSS class (called "class1" for purposes of this question) to the top ten results in the query.  How can I do this?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
$result = mysql_query($sqlStr3);
$count = 1;  
$arr = array();
echo "<table class=\"samplesrec1edit\">";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td class="sitename1edit2a">'.$count++.'.</td>';
        echo '<td class="sitename1edit1"><a href="http://www...com/../members/index.php?profile='.$row["username"].'">'.stripslashes($row["username"]).'</a></td>';
        echo '<td class="sitename1edit2">'.number_format(($row["totalScore2"])).'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        }
    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this:

```
$result = mysql_query($sqlStr3);
$count = 1;  
$arr = array();
echo "<table class=\"samplesrec1edit\">";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        if($count < 11){
            echo '<tr class="top-10">';
        }else{
            echo '<tr class="non-top-10">';
        }
            echo '<td class="sitename1edit2a">'.$count++.'.</td>';
        echo '<td class="sitename1edit1"><a href="http://www...com/../members/index.php?profile='.$row["username"].'">'.stripslashes($row["username"]).'</a></td>';
        echo '<td class="sitename1edit2">'.number_format(($row["totalScore2"])).'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        }
echo "</table>";
```

access the td of top10 using this css

```
.top-10 td{
//definitions
}
```

and access the td of non top10 lines with

```
.non-top-10 td{
//definitions
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
... class="...<?php if ($count <= 10) { ?> class1<?php } ?>" ...
```

And move the increment to the end of the loop.

Comment: Where it assigns the `class` attribute for the tag.

Comment: Okay... for the table CSS or the column CSS?

Comment: Wherever you would put it if you were just writing straight HTML.

Comment: Okay... but where do I put the non-top-10 classes?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in the **server side** via php like:

```
 echo '<tr '.($count <=10 ? 'myclass' : '').' > ;
```

or in jquery in **front side** like:

```
$("someTableSelector").find("tr:lt(10)").addClass('myclass')
```

Answer (score 0):

How about assigning each result from TOP10 a unique class called top_result_[n]?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo '<tr'.($count++ <=10 ? ' class="top_result_'.$count.'"' : '').'>';
        echo '<td class="sitename1edit2a">'.$count.'.</td>';
        echo '<td class="sitename1edit1"><a href="http://www...com/../members/index.php?profile='.$row["username"].'">'.stripslashes($row["username"]).'</a></td>';
        echo '<td class="sitename1edit2">'.number_format(($row["totalScore2"])).'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        }
    echo "</table>";
```

I'm not sure wether you want to apply ONE class for all 10 results or UNIQUE class for each from 10 results, as for the first case, the code would be:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
        echo '<tr'.($count++ <=10 ? ' class="top_result"' : '').'>';
        echo '<td class="sitename1edit2a">'.$count.'.</td>';
        echo '<td class="sitename1edit1"><a href="http://www...com/../members/index.php?profile='.$row["username"].'">'.stripslashes($row["username"]).'</a></td>';
        echo '<td class="sitename1edit2">'.number_format(($row["totalScore2"])).'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        }
    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS:

```
.samplesrec1edit tr:nth-child(-n+10) { 
   cssrule:value;
}
```

This technique only works in newer browsers however. The following link has compatibility  charts.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthchild

Comment: I'm in a very rare but fortunate situation where I can guarantee that users of my application all use html5 webkit browsers. I only belatedly put the new browser caveat into my answer as it slips my mind regularly.