# Adding CSS class to elements using mysql query results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem here. I've tried searching everywhere but can't seems to find it. I know there's post about this out there, maybe I can't get my search query right.

It's similar to this 2 that I've found:
[Applying different CSS to top 10 results of a query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3904976/applying-different-css-to-top-10-results-of-a-query)
[.addClass with IF statement based on value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10524751/addclass-with-if-statement-based-on-value)

Currently here's a brief example of my code:

```
<?php
$select=mysql_query("select * from products_list ORDER BY id ASC");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)){
echo "<tr>
<td>".$row['id']."</td>
<td>".$row['title']."</td>
<td>".$row['new_arrival']."</td>";
?>
```

The data for new_arrival in the database is either yes or no.

My question is how do I add a class for the "new_arrival" on the TD if it is "yes" and no class added if it is "no"

Hope you guys understand what I'm trying to say. Thanks.

Regards,
Jeff

Comment: As stated in the PHP manual for the [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function: *Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.*

Comment: Omg.. I'm still new to this mysql thingy and yet I didn't know the one I'm using already deprecated.. =(

Comment: Don't worry--it's easy to switch (especially to MySQLi, which for the most part is just a simple case of adding the letter `i` into your function names).

Comment: I see. Ok, I will read up and try to edit that. =S Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    $select = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM products_list ORDER BY id ASC" );
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $select ) ) {

        $class = '';
        if ( $row[ 'new_arrival' ] == 'yes' )
            $class = ' class="your_class" ';

        $result = "<tr>
                    <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>
                    <td" . $class. ">" . $row['new_arrival']  ."</td>
                  </tr>";

        echo $result;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple if statement if `new_arrival == yes` you add the class else lets it empty

```
$select=mysql_query("select * from products_list ORDER BY id ASC");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)){
    $class = ($row['new_arrival'] == 'yes') ? 'class="new_arrival"' : '';
    echo "<tr>
    <td ".$class.">".$row['id']."</td>
    <td ".$class.">".$row['title']."</td>
    <td ".$class.">".$row['new_arrival']."</td></tr>";
}
```

Comment: I guess that 
$class = ($row['new_arrival'] == 'yes') ? 'class="new_arrival"' : '';
works the same as
$class = '';
        if ( $row[ 'new_arrival' ] == 'yes' )
            $class=' class="your_class" ';
right??

Thou I didn't use this code but could you kindly explain to me? Because I'm new to this and does not understand that. =x

Comment: It's a ternaire test `$var = (test) ? true : false;` give the same result than `if (test) { $var = true; } else { $var = false; }`

Comment: I see, seems abit confusing. =x Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$select=mysql_query("select * from products_list ORDER BY id ASC");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)){
echo "<tr>
<td>".$row['id']."</td>
<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
  if(if($row['new_arrival']=='yes')
  {
   echo "<td class='classname'>".$row['new_arrival']."</td>";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<td>".$row['new_arrival']."</td>";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this an simple IF

```
echo "<tr>
<td>".$row['id']."</td>
<td>".$row['title']."</td>";
if($row["new_arrival"] == "yes"){
 echo "<td class='positive'>".$row["new_arrival"]."</td>"; //yes
}else{
 echo "<td>".$row['new_arrival']."</td>"; // no
}
```